# Parsing XML in C# with "floating" structure and populating listbox

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

Have an XML file with following structure.

```
<books>
    <myonlystore>
        <book1>
            <author>Book1 author</author>
            <title>Book1 Title</title>
        </book1>
        <book2>
            <author>Book2 author</author>
            <title>Book2 Title</title>
        </book2>
        <book3>
            <author>Book3 author</author>
            <title>Book3 Title</title>
            <ISBN>12345</ISBN>
        </book3>
    </myonlystore>
</books>
```

trying to get book1, book2 and book3 into the listbox and upon selection show respective available attributes. But got confused with an XML structure. Please advise how to read properly this file.

Thank you

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! Could you show how you are trying to parse xml? I would use <book> </book> rather that book1, book2, book3.. so on.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that is the format I get. That is the place where I got confused: book1, book2, and book3 look like attributes of "myonlystore" rather than standalone elements with own attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XDocumnet like so:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root
    .Descendants().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("book"))
    .Select(b => new
    {
        Author = (string) b.Element("author"),
        Title = (string) b.Element("title"),
        Isbn = (string) b.Element("ISBN")
    });
```

---

**Updated:**

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xml).Root.Element("myonlystore")
    .Elements()
    .Select(b => new
    {
        Author = (string) b.Element("author"),
        Title = (string) b.Element("title"),
        Isbn = (string) b.Element("ISBN")
    });
```

Comment: Hi Kirill, Thanks for the reply, unfortunately as per my comment below I cannot use StartsWith("book")). How I can see it - just use "books/myonlystore" as a root and then get all child items with their attribute. But I cannot say for sure that all 3 of attributes will be present.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file would be better organized if it were referenced with the `<store> <books>` category, so it's simple to list all the books in the store as per the code below.

XML File:

```
<myonlystore>
  <books>
    <author>Book1 author</author>
    <title>Book1 Title</title>
  </books>
  <books>
    <author>Book2 author</author>
    <title>Book2 Title</title>
  </books>
  <books>
    <author>Book3 author</author>
    <title>Book3 Title</title>
    <ISBN>12345</ISBN>
  </books>
</myonlystore>
```

And the code to read the XML file:

```
    public static void ReadXmlFile1()
    {
        String path = $@"{desk}\xmlfile.xml";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XDocument.Load(path).ToString());

        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("books"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Element("author").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(element.Element("title").Value);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Unfortunately this is the format I have. It is not consistent. Some books have ISBN attribute, some don't. Additionally, not all elements start with "book" so I cannot use contractions like ".StartsWith("book")" , etc. So basically I just need to list all standalone elements after "myonlystore" and their attributes, if any are present.